# CouchDB Error 500: function_clause error in HTTP request

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchdb

When making a REST call to CouchDB, the request fails with unknown error 500.  Any help would be much appreciated... thanks!

Here are the logs:

```
    [Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:47:50 GMT] [debug] [] 'GET' /settings/master-config? {1,1} from "10.48.XX.XXX"
    Headers: [{'Authorization',"Basic XXX=, Basic XXX=="},
        {'Connection',"Keep-Alive"},
        {'Host',"127.0.0.1:5984"},
        {'User-Agent',"Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)"},
        {'X-Forwarded-For',"10.48.xx.xxx"},
        {"X-Forwarded-Host","my.couchdb.server.com"},
        {"X-Forwarded-Server","ip-10-48-xx-xxx.ec2.internal"},
        {"X-Newrelic-Id","XXXX="},
        {"X-NewRelic-Transaction","XXXXXXX"}]
    [Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:47:50 GMT] [debug] [] OAuth Params: []
    [Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:47:50 GMT] [error] [] function_clause error in HTTP request
    [Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:47:50 GMT] [info] [] Stacktrace: [{base64,b64d_ok,[eq]},
        {base64,decode,2},
        {base64,decode,1},
        {couch_httpd_auth,basic_name_pw,1},
        {couch_httpd_auth,
        default_authentication_handler,1},
        {couch_httpd,authenticate_request,2},
        {couch_httpd,handle_request_int,5},
        {mochiweb_http,headers,5}]
    [Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:47:50 GMT] [info] [] 10.48.XX.XXX - - GET /settings/master-config? 500
    [Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:47:50 GMT] [error] [] httpd 500 error response:
     {"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Authorization header looks weird: `{'Authorization',"Basic XXX=, Basic XXX=="}` - there should be only single Basic credentials token, not multiple ones.

Comment: Good catch!  I'll look into this and definitely accept your answer if it works.  Thanks!